# Using Exceptions to control application flow

Tags: php, oop, exception

I am currently writing a web app in PHP and have decided to use exceptions (duh!).

I could not find an answer to whether putting try and catch blocks in all functions would be considered bad code.

I am currently using Exceptions to handle Database errors (Application errors are handled via a simple function which just adds them to an array and then they are displayed to the user). The try blocks are placed on all functions which require a database connection.

The code in question is:

```
public function db_conn_verify()
{
    if(!isset($this->_mysqli)){
        throw new Exception("Network Error: Database connection could not be established.");
    } else {
        return Null;
    }
}
```

And an example function using this code:

```
public function get_users() {
    try {
        $this->db_conn_verify();

        //Rest of function code

        return True;

    } Catch(Exception $e) {
        Core::system_error('function get_users()', $e->getMessage());
        return False;
    }
}
```

Also would it be better to extend the Exception class and then use that new Exception class to handle application errors?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to you to use something like this:

```
public function get_users() {

        try {
            if( !isset($this->_mysqli) ) {
                 throw new Exception("Network Error: Database connection could not be established.");
            }

            //Rest of function code

        } Catch(Exception $e) {
            Core::system_error('function get_users()', $e->getMessage());
        }
}
```

I prefer to use my exends of Exception, but is the same. For exdending exception you can see the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) to Example #5

**EDIT:** For an immediate use of try-catch on database connection error you can try this:

```
try{
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        throw new Exception("Network Error: Database connection could not be established.");
    }
} Catch(Exception $e) {
  Core::system_error('function get_users()', $e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about doing this before I came up with my solution but what I was thinking is that this is going to be duplicated quiet a lot of times which is going to make re-factoring (if needed) much longer.

Comment: Maybe you can put the try-catch block in db connection function, so each time you need the connection, if not working you see an exception.

Comment: But would that stop the flow of the function?

Comment: Yes, because Exception make a fatal error that stops all process.